# Get bottom value of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<div id="xx" style="bottom:20px;"></div>`

How do I get the bottom value of `#xx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
document.getElementById('xx').style.bottom;
```

You'll get the string `'20px'`.

If you want it as a number, you'll have to parse it :

```
var nb = parseInt(document.getElementById('xx').style.bottom, 10);
```

Comment: It is best to use getElementById since it is faster, but if you want to do it in jquery you can do $('#xx').css('bottom');

Comment: And if jquery, `$('#xx').css('bottom')`?

Comment: Come on, you know to include the radix for `parseInt` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery:

```
$('#xx').css('bottom');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you didn't test. This would get "auto".

Comment: @dystroy - well it should unless a position is specified since bottom alone is meaningless. If a position, like `position:relative` is also specified, then it returns the correct `20px`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YRM7B/